# Run program on guest OS in VirtualBox

Tags: python, virtual-machine, command-line-interface, virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox 5.0.16 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have virtual machine  with 32-bit version of Windows7. What I want to do is to run program on the guest. First I tried using Python script for this purpose:

```
vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
session = virtualbox.Session()
vm = vbox.find_machine('Windows7')
vm.launch_vm_process(session, 'gui', '').wait_for_completion()

session = vm.create_session()
time.sleep(35)
gs = session.console.guest.create_session('win7', '')
process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe', ['/C', 'tasklist'])
print stdout
```

Machine starts well, but I can't run any program because something raises following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "runonguest.py", line 39, in
>   
>       gs = session.console.guest.create_session('win7', '')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualbox/library_ext/guest.py",
>   line 24, in create_session
>       raise SystemError("GuestSession failed to start") SystemError: GuestSession failed to start

After I tried using command-line in order to run program on the guest. So I have running virtual machine, and trying to execute following command:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "Windows7" --username win7 run --exe C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe  --wait-stdout  -- "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/C" "tasklist"
```

But it brings me next error:

> VBoxManage: error: VERR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED VBoxManage: error: Details:
>   code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component GuestSessionWrap,
>   interface IGuestSession, callee nsISupports VBoxManage: error:
>   Context: "WaitForArray(ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aSessionWaitFlags), 30 *
>   1000, &enmWaitResult)" at line 938 of file VBoxManageGuestCtrl.cpp

I was searching for possible solutions but most of them for older versions of VirtualBox where command **run** doesn't exist at all.
It would be nice if somebody knows any possible solution. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access [Start menu] and in [search program and files] type **Run**.
Inside [Run line] type **gpedit.msc**.
There, go to Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> [**Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only**] and set it to **Disabled**. After a VM restart, should be solved.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even think in that direction. It works just fine now.

Comment: I didn't either at the moment I had this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

So far I managed to launch program on the guest OS in VirtualBox.
The solution based on the (undocumented as I see) fact that VBox API just doesn't launch session in case user account has no password. So I created new user account with password on guest's Windows7.

For Python just write:

```
    In [15]: gs = session.console.guest.create_session('user', 'user')

    In [16]: process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe', ['/C', 'tasklist'])

    In [17]: print stdout

    Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
    ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
    System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         12 K
    System                           4 Services                   0        528 K
    smss.exe                       264 Services                   0        688 K
    csrss.exe                      340 Services                   0      2,824 K
    wininit.exe                    388 Services                   0      3,128 K
    csrss.exe                      400                            1      3,572 K
    winlogon.exe                   440                            1      5,556 K 
.....
```

For console use just write:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "Windows7" --verbose  --username user --password user run --exe "C:\\
Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe" -- cmd.exe /c tasklist

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         12 K
System                           4 Services                   0        532 K
smss.exe                       264 Services                   0        688 K
csrss.exe                      340 Services                   0      2,848 K
wininit.exe                    388 Services                   0      3,128 K
csrss.exe                      400                            1      3,572 K
winlogon.exe                   440                            1      5,556 K
......
```

Launch details:

python 2.7.6
pyvbox 1.0.0
Host OS - Ubuntu 14.04
Guest OS - Windows7 x32

VirtualBox 5.0.16

**UPD:** According to **iugene's** answer the real solution was in Windows security policies.

> Access [Start menu] and in [search program and files] type Run. Inside
>   [Run line] type gpedit.msc. There, go to Windows Settings -> Security
>   Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> [Accounts: Limit
>   local account use of blank passwords to console logon only] and set it
>   to Disabled. After a VM restart, should be solved.